# $|\mathcal{o}(f(x))| \leq \mathcal{o}(|f(x)|)$

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Let f(x) be a real continuous function

Is it true that
$|\mathcal{o}(f(x))| \leq \mathcal{o}(|f(x)|)$

thanks.

P.S.
$g(x)=\mathcal{o}(f(x))$ if $\lim \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0$

Comment: as written, the claim doesn't make any sense. Do you mean let $g\in o(f(x)),h\in o(|f(x)|)$, then $\limsup g/h \leq 1$?

Comment: @Andrew no, i mean if $g(x)=o(f(x))$ and $h(x)=o(|f(x)|)$ then $|g(x)| \leq h(x)$

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you mean when you write landau notation

Comment: Do you really believe that if $g/f\to0$ and $h/|f|\to0$ then necessarily $|g|\le h?$ Or even (taking $f$ constantly equal to $1$): that if $g\to0$ and $h\to0$ then $|g|\le h?$

Comment: Thanks @AnneBauval no I don't think

Comment: So the answer to your question (as reformulated in your comment) is obviously no. But maybe your comment doesn't correspond to what you had in mind? Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @AnneBauval I meant just what you said that the answer is obviously no. Your example was enlightening